# animate list of UIView which can be UIButton or UIImageView sequentially using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

I am trying to make a function that I have already done for android.
That function was able to take list of Views, and it will display them sequentially.
it was something like this:

```
void displayViews(List<View> listOfViews, int delayTime, CompletionListener listner{
    // code of applying animation on the views here
    int startDelay = mDelay; // milliseconds
        int numberOfViews = listOfViews.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
            final Animation animator = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.FadeIn);
            animator.setStartOffset(startDelay);
            startDelay += mOffSet; // every view will start after 100 milliseconds from the other
            final View currentView = listOfViews.get(i);
            final int indexOfCurrentCheckedItem = i;

            animator.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    // if index of current item == number of views, SO this is the last view
                    //      in the list, which means the animation is finished, lets do what
                    //         we wanna after the animation finishes
                    if (listener != null) {
                        if (indexOfCurrentCheckedItem == mNumOfViews - 1)
                            listner.doIt();
                    } 
                    // after animation finishes
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            });

            mMainUIThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    currentView.startAnimation(animator);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

so that using this function i will start the animation for each view with delay, when the last animation finished the completion listener will be triggered.

I checked for function that might help me in UIView functions i couldnt find. I need something like `view.setAnimationWithDelay`

**Question 1**
Can I add animation for UIView in swift by having reference to it?

**Question 2**
Is it possible to pass what animation i want to apply on the listOfViews using ?

Comment: `UIView.animateWithDuration( .. , delay: .. , options: .. , animations: .. , completion ..)`.

Comment: how can i specify for which view this will be done? for example in android i write for every view, view.startAnimation(animation).  her u used UIView which is the general class, not the object @IanMacDonald

Comment: It will apply to any property modified within the `animations` block.

Comment: @IanMacDonald so I will try to loop and call UIView.animateWithDuration function every time with different delay to check whether it does the work